# Reaching URL limit while using react-router in a complex application having too many params to consider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The React application I'm working on is a huge dashboard that needs to load a specific configuration given a well-defined URL.

I want to pass multiple params to my route and I'm not sure how to do it in the best way without reaching the limit of a URL string (<2048).

Is there a solution that keeps the URL readable and editable and keeps me from hitting the limit mentioned above?

Comment: Is required that all the params are on the URL?, you can express those params as a group?, for example: This specific configuration is for management, this is for consultants, etc etc.

Comment: Hey @bilelMbkCg can you provide an example? Are those params necessary for the page state to load or can they be shifted to the app state?

Comment: Hey @Matthi, as an example, the app should be able to load a list of checkboxes where the checked/unchecked elements are specified in the GET URL

Comment: Will it affect the rest of the page or does it work as a preset? A filter in a shop might affect the list of showed articles. Then those parameters in the URL would be understandable. If it is just a user preset, can you work with the app state (for example with redux or React Context?

Comment: Yes @Matthi, they are mostly filters.

Comment: If it is a yes/no thing, can you add something like `?checked=a,b,c,d,e,f,g` instead of `?a=checked&b=checked&c=checked&d=checked&e=checked&f=checked&g=checked`

Comment: @Matthi, I've implemented it this way `url/a/b/c/d/e/f/g` but instead of letters, they're words or phrases

Comment: Is the URL shareable? If not, you could make use of localStorage instead of adding to the URL.

Comment: @Matthi, exactly, the whole purpose is to make the URL shareable

Comment: I see. I think this is kind of bad URL design. There might be use cases for seo, but in your case with the dashboard, parameters should stay parameters

Comment: If everything has to be shareable, you could save the state in a key value store on the server and use a link shortener to load the page with the right presets in the source code. The URL would be something like `?settings=j45kad` and on the server the state will be loaded from the key value store and rendered into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, consider sacrificing readability.

Comment: Should I sacrifice using React Router as well? if so what are the alternatives?

Comment: I'd keep React Router. I think it's a browser limit.

Comment: It is indeed a browser limit, but the lengthy succession of the params split by slashes `../../..` is the root of this problem, a consequence of using React Router.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: It's a dashboard, filtered by multiple parameters in a checkbox list, the URL should contain a list of the checked/unchecked elements and load the page according to the query fields. Those params are passed as props to the child components in the main dashboard.